# How set sprite position in corner of other sprite?

Tags: android, sprite

I have a `GameObject` with a sprite. How can I get the sprite's:

- top-left corner position?
- top-right corner position?
- down-left corner position?
- down-right corner position?

I would like to put other sprites in the corners of the first one, but I have no idea how. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, are you objects center based or top_left based? Either way, you have a Rectangle that you must sum with either of the position you use to know the corner

Comment: In order to answer that, I need to know two things first: the orientation of your cartesian plane axises ( does the "y" axis points up or down?); which part of the sprite is represented in it's position (is it the sprite's center?).